# email Model and email column clashing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, database-design

I have a **Submitter** Model which has an **email** column. I also have an **Email** Model that has email **suffix** column in it.

My issue (I believe) is that since my Submitter Model has an email column, when I try to use `submitter.email.suffix` to display the suffix in my Email model it says there's no defined method.

Any idea what I can do here?

View:

```
<% @submitters.each do |submitter| %>  <tr>
<td><%= submitter.school.name %></td>
<td><%= submitter.first_name %></td>
<td><%= submitter.last_name %></td>
<td><%= submitter.email %><%= submitter.email.suffix %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show', submitter %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_submitter_path(submitter) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', submitter, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

As a side note I have no problem showing the IDs of the emails suffix but obviously I'm trying to show the actual suffix instead:

```
<td><%= submitter.email %><%= submitter.email_suffix_id %></td>
```

**Submitter.rb** has a `has many :emails` and **Email.rb** has a `belongs_to :submitter` association.

Comment: is `suffix` an email's method?

Comment: `suffix` is a column in my **Email** model, so I assume it is..

Answer (score 0):

So let's break this down. You say you're trying to do

```
submitter.email.suffix
```

however, your model has no such `:email` association. Instead you've stated your `Submitter` model has

```
has_many :emails
```

This would mean:

1. To print the `:email` attribute on some `Submitter` instance `submitter`, use

   ```
   puts submitter.email
   ```
2. To print the `:prefix` attribute of each `Email` instance related to `submitter` via your `has_many` association, you'd need to loop over them

   ```
   submitter.emails.each do |e|
     puts e.suffix
   done
   ```

It's still quite unclear what exactly you're **trying** to do, but hopefully this clears up some confusion on your end; **there is no method naming conflict** so far.

Comment: this give me the same error as before, weirdly enough. thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: To be more specific the error is `undefined method 'suffix' for "Devin.ODaniel":String` where `Devin.ODaniel` is what's stored in my `:email` attribute.  So it's seeing the *email* in `submitter.email.suffix` as a method rather than trying to access my Email model.  Does this help any?

Comment: I think you're ignoring my advice. `submitter.email` returns a String such as `"Devin.ODaniel"`, **not** an `Email` model. You get the `undefined method 'suffix' error` because **you're calling `suffix` on a `String` instance, *not* an instance of `Email`**. You have said your `Submitter` **`has_many :emails`**. If you want to call `suffix` on one of `Submitter`'s related `Email` instances *(for example, the first in the collection)* you could do `submitter.emails.first.suffix`.

Answer (score 0):

`submitter.email.suffix` won't work because it returns Submitter "email" which is a string, not the Email instance.

```
submitter.emails.each(&:suffix)
```

should work. `submitter.emails` will return an Email's instances and they do have `suffix` method(according to your words).

Comment: This returns the same error also. Maybe I have my associations wrong?

Comment: To be more specific the error is `undefined method 'suffix' for "Devin.ODaniel":String` where `Devin.ODaniel` is what's stored in my `:email` attribute.  So it's seeing the *email* in `submitter.email.suffix` as a method rather than trying to access my Email model.  Does this help any?